# How do I use an async method while implementing a sync method?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I am trying to implement an interface using the help of some code that is async.  How can I do this?

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import asyncio

class SomeInterface():
    def some_method(self, s):
        pass

class MyImpl(SomeInterface):
    def __init__(self, helper_async_obj):
        self.helper = helper_async_obj

    def some_method(self, s):
        print("before using async helper")
        # TODO: I want to call self.helper.f(s) here. If this was an async method, I would just do:
        # await self.helper.f(s)
        print("after async helper is done")

class AsyncHelper():
    async def f(self, s):
        print(f"before sleep: {s}")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print(f"after sleep: {s}")

async def main():
    ah = AsyncHelper()
    my_impl = MyImpl(ah)
    my_impl.some_method("hello")
    # wait forever
    await asyncio.get_running_loop().create_future()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

I expect the output to look like this:

```
before using async helper
before sleep: hello
after sleep: hello
after using async helper
```

The issue is that I want to run an async method from a sync method and I want the async method to finish executing before I return from the sync method.  How can I do this?  I can't just do `task = asyncio.create_task(self.helper.f(s))` because that will return immediately and execute in the background, not block the caller until the task is done.

Comment: It looks like you want to synchronize the execution of the async method `self.helper.f` which may not be ideal. Why is `f` async if it needs to be called in a sync manner? But, here are some workarounds: (1) try running `asyncio.run(self.helper.f(s))` within `some_method`, (2)  Move contents of async `f` into a sync method `_f` and then have `f` call `_f`. Now, call the sync`self.helper._f(s)` from `some_method`, instead of calling the async `self.helper.f(s)` and get the same effect, (3) Consider using threads+locks if synchronization is important, (4) Consider overall code logic reorg.

Comment: This sounds like a bad idea. Python has a tool specifically for calling an async function and waiting until it's done, and that tool is `await`. If you won't use `await`, you better have a very good reason for that. Especially since your `main` function is already async - implementing a part of the program in synchronous mode is like purposely shooting yourself in the foot.